# fadeIn() and fadeOut() working partially, unable to hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

```js
var $a = $('.a'),
  $b = $('.b'),
  $c = $('.c'),
  $d = $('.d'),
  $home = $('.home'),
  $about = $('.about'),
  $gallery = $('.gallery'),
  $contact = $('.contact');

$a.click(function() {
  $home.fadeIn();
  $about.fadeOut();
  $gallery.fadeOut();
  $contact.fadeOut();
});
$b.click(function() {
  $about.fadeIn();
  $home.fadeOut();
  $gallery.fadeOut();
  $contact.fadeOut();
});
$c.click(function() {
  $gallery.fadeIn();
  $about.fadeOut();
  $contact.fadeOut();
  $home.fadeOut();
});
$d.click(function() {
  $contact.fadeIn();
  $about.fadeOut();
  $home.fadeOut();
  $gallery.fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact">
  <div class="contactForm">
    <form action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="text" class="inputText" name="" value="First Name">
      <input type="text" class="inputText" name="" value="Last Name">
      <input type="text" class="inputText" name="" value="Your Email">
      <textarea class="inputMessage" name="" id="" cols="4" rows="6">Your Message</textarea>
      <input class="submitButton" type="button" name="" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every div is working fine, except the Contact div, and I unable to recognize why.

Live error: www.jibranyousuf.com

You will see the contact form when the page loads, although it should only be displayed when I click on Contact Us.

Comment: What should (beside visiting your website) make us think that the contact form should be initially hidden - **by the question-provided code**? P.S: you have no styles set for `.contact` - the reason your `.contact` element is not acting like the other ones. Also, your entire JS could be re-written in a couple of lines. See the pattern?

Comment: Right off the bat you set up a bunch of objects with no matching class in the HTML. `var $a = $('.a'),
  $b = $('.b'),
  $c = $('.c'),
  $d = $('.d'),
  $home = $('.home'),
  $about = $('.about'),
  $gallery = $('.gallery'),
  $contact = $('.contact');`

Comment: Please provide a working minimal example

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, You are correct, I just added the styles for .contact and now it works fine.
I am just trying to learn the basics of HTML CSS, and that is why I opted on a simple website to know the basics.
I will surely move on to JS.
Thank You.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss those a,b,c,d are classes for NavBar, yeah I didn't name them correctly.

Comment: @JibranYousuf it seems like you've found the answer to your question. If one of answers below fits, you may consider marking it as the answer for others or upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do not know if I understood the question well, as far as I can tell, all your divs contain a `display: none` in the style.css file, so they are hidden in the page application, but the "contact" div does not have this "display: none" in style.css, he has no class, for example "about" div:

```
.about{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-family: century 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0 60px;
    display: none;
}
```

try add this on your style.css file:

```
.contact{
    display: none;
}
```

Sorry about my english